# How can I check, if all divs are fully visible inside an other div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div, called "wrapper", with responsive height and overflow-y auto (so scroll enabled). Inside this div are lots of other divs, called "box". So, for example, if there are 3 divs inside the wrapper and I see them all fully, nothing should happen. But if any of this divs inside the wrapper are not fully visible **(on page load and page resize)**, an other div (called "button") should fadeIn.

I just found this post, but it doesn´t solve my problem:
[stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797375/check-if-element-is-fully-visible-in-overflow-scrolling-div)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
</div>

<div class="button">
My Button
</div>
```

My fiddle:
[HTML + CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/ym0k187s/)

How can I check, if all divs are **fully visible** inside an other div (on page load and page resize)?

#

**UPDATE:**
My problem is, that "viewport" doesnt work for me, because the script has also to check what happens outside the viewport (dynamically). The height of my divs is responsive and so not every time all of it is in the viewport ...

... but for me, I found an other solution. Now I check the height of my main div (my main content) and if this div is smaller than the "wrapper" div, I will fadeIn the "button" div.

Comment: Read this: [How to tell if a dom element is visible in the current viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Comment: @OB FullStack Kenobi Thx for the post, but I found an other solution for me ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this my friend"

```
 if ($(".wrapper div").css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
  // ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

When hosting your HTML:

- Right click on your `wrapper` and inspect element
- Hover over the first `div` inside of the `wrapper`, and it should become highlighted
- Check to see if that `div` is visible on the page
- Continue the above steps for every `div` in your `wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve a problem that's the same as, or very similar to, the problem you're describing:

[zeusdeux/isInViewport](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport)

The "examples" folder includes various examples where DIVs react to whether or not they are contained within a defined viewport div.

EDIT:  After reading comments on the question, this seems to be the best resource for reading up on the general problem and solutions (even though `isInViewport` looks very useful as well):

[How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433)

Comment: Thx for your support! My problem is, that "viewport" doesnt work for me, because the script has also to check what happens outside the viewport (dynamically). The height of my divs is responsive and so not every time all of it is in the viewpoint - I hope you understand what I mean? But the "height - check - way" works for me ...